# VB.Net Picturebox "Parameter is not Valid" when get online images

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

```vb
Dim ShowImgWebClient = New WebClient
Dim ImageInBytes As Byte() = ShowImgWebClient.DownloadData("http://ex.domain.com/index.php?checksum=" & lblCheckSum.Text.ToString())
Dim ImageStream As New MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)
Dim CaptchaImg As Image = New Bitmap(ImageStream)
ptbCaptcha.Image = CaptchaImg
```

I'm use this code for get online captcha to my picturebox name **ptbCaptcha**.

but when request this image my program show error **Parameter is not Valid**.

Why this ? and How to make it work ?

Comment: Might be this : `lblCheckSum.Text`. Remove `.ToString()`. It is already a string..

Comment: Was the error caused from this?

Comment: **Dim ImageStream As New MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)**

Comment: On which line does the error occur? What's the exact message (include stack trace, if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to use `MemoryStream`.

Here is the example taken from microsoft website :

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module MemStream

    Sub Main()

        Dim count As Integer 
        Dim byteArray As Byte()
        Dim charArray As Char()
        Dim uniEncoding As New UnicodeEncoding()

        ' Create the data to write to the stream. 
        Dim firstString As Byte() = _
            uniEncoding.GetBytes("Invalid file path characters are: ")
        Dim secondString As Byte() = _
            uniEncoding.GetBytes(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())

        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(100)
        Try 
            ' Write the first string to the stream.
            memStream.Write(firstString, 0 , firstString.Length)

            ' Write the second string to the stream, byte by byte.
            count = 0
            While(count < secondString.Length)
                memStream.WriteByte(secondString(count))
                count += 1
            End While 

            ' Write the stream properties to the console.
            Console.WriteLine( _
                "Capacity = {0}, Length = {1}, Position = {2}", _
                memStream.Capacity.ToString(), _
                memStream.Length.ToString(), _
                memStream.Position.ToString())

            ' Set the stream position to the beginning of the stream.
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

            ' Read the first 20 bytes from the stream.
            byteArray = _
                New Byte(CType(memStream.Length, Integer)){}
            count = memStream.Read(byteArray, 0, 20)

            ' Read the remaining Bytes, Byte by Byte. 
            While(count < memStream.Length)
                byteArray(count) = _
                    Convert.ToByte(memStream.ReadByte())
                count += 1
            End While 

            ' Decode the Byte array into a Char array  
            ' and write it to the console.
            charArray = _
                New Char(uniEncoding.GetCharCount( _
                byteArray, 0, count)){}
            uniEncoding.GetDecoder().GetChars( _
                byteArray, 0, count, charArray, 0)
            Console.WriteLine(charArray)
        Finally
            memStream.Close()
        End Try 

    End Sub 
End Module
```

See [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.